# Android sample screens with their source xml code

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I looked at individual layouts and views [(here)](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html), but I still cannot decide which layout to use for which condition. I was wondering if there is a site where there are some sample android screens having multiple layouts with their xml source code.

Comment: Go with the layout that meets your needs; no need to over think it.

Comment: keep it simple, android already provides all you need, almost ;)

Comment: @sebataz I mean, I want to see some samples where there are multiple views and layouts used in order to create a screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: [XML Layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)